# Who is the final boss of Street Fighter IV?

Tags: street-fighter-iv

I'm trying to sign up for the [Shoryuken](http://www.shoryuken.com) forums to discuss Marvel vs. Capcom 3 and the registration page asks me who the final boss of Street Fighter IV is to prove I'm not a computer.

I've never played that game, so I don't know the answer.

Comment: I'm all for spam traps but some forums can be a little too exclusive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Seth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_characters_in_the_Street_Fighter_series#Seth) is the name of the final boss of Street Fighter IV.

Comment: Although you can fight with Akuma or Gouken after beating seth. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16791/how-to-unlock-all-sf4-characters-on-pc